# Error Invalid content was found starting with element . No child element is expected at this point

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have an error with my web service.
The error is :

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'callerNumber'. No child element is expected at this point.

The service send the object RelationCARO contains 3 strings : caName, roName and callerNumber (optional).

When callerNumber is NULL, it works, and when callerNumber is not NULL, I have the above error.

When I try to call the service with soapUI, it works even with callerNumber.

The WSDL :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="RMDManagementService"   targetNamespace="http://ws.mom.rmd.atos.net/ws"     xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.mom.rmd.atos.net/ws" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.mom.rmd.atos.net/ws" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://ws.mom.rmd.atos.net/ws" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xs:element name="createRelationCaRo" type="tns:createRelationCaRo" />
        <xs:element name="createRelationCaRoResponse" type="tns:createRelationCaRoResponse" />

        <xs:complexType name="createRelationCaRo">
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="relationCaRo" type="tns:relationCaRo" />
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="relationCaRo">
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="caName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="roName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="callerNumber" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="createRelationCaRoResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:relationCaRoFeedback" />
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="relationCaRoFeedback">
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="caName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="roName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="statusReturnCode" type="tns:statusReturnCodeEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>


        <xs:simpleType name="statusReturnCodeEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="CDE_RMD000" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CDE_RMD001" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CDE_RMD300" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CDE_RMD303" />
        <xs:enumeration value="CDE_RMD304" />
        </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>

        </xs:schema>
          </wsdl:types>
          <wsdl:message name="createRelationCaRo">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:createRelationCaRo" name="parameters">
            </wsdl:part>
          </wsdl:message>
          <wsdl:message name="createRelationCaRoResponse">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:createRelationCaRoResponse" name="parameters">
            </wsdl:part>
          </wsdl:message>

          <wsdl:portType name="RMDManagement">
            <wsdl:operation name="createRelationCaRo">
              <wsdl:input message="tns:createRelationCaRo" name="createRelationCaRo">
            </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output message="tns:createRelationCaRoResponse" name="createRelationCaRoResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>
          </wsdl:portType>
          <wsdl:binding name="RMDManagementServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:RMDManagement">
            <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
            <wsdl:operation name="createRelationCaRo">
              <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
              <wsdl:input name="createRelationCaRo">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output name="createRelationCaRoResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>
          </wsdl:binding>
          <wsdl:service name="RMDManagementService">
            <wsdl:port binding="tns:RMDManagementServiceSoapBinding" name="RMDManagementSOAPPort">
              <soap:address location="http://...../RMDManagementService" />

            </wsdl:port>
          </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

On the client side, I generated all classes with wsdl2java.

I don't understand the problem, because there are only 3 strings, and no children in parameter.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your wsdl is totaly fine. 
Post your code here please (message context part and soap envelop creation  also), i am not able to figure out your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put the code online at this address: http://www.4shared.com/folder/XAwiwIAx/_online.html

Comment: dude, what is this link? :(. Please paste the code here. It looks like spam site. sadness.